# package.el: How can I avoid byte-compilation

Tags: package, byte-compilation

How can I tell package.el to not byte-compile?

It is generally OK to byte-compile installed packages but it makes difficult to test a new Emacs with byte compiler improvements (such as Emacs 26 from 25) if you share `.emacs/elpa/` with old Emacsen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a `~/.emacs.d/elpa/.dir-locals.el` file containing:

```
((emacs-lisp-mode . ((no-byte-compile . t))))
```

`no-byte-compile` is generally intended to be used as a file-local variable (see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Byte Compilation` <kbd>RET</kbd>), but a quick experiment suggests that it works just fine as a dir-local, and successfully inhibits byte compilation when installing ELPA packages.